# mysql fetching data pass through function

Tags: php, fpdf

** Here is the code,and how to retrieve mysql data, pass through the function and print it. i try this but show an error in function part like GenerateName(), GeneratePrice(), GenerateCode() section. How to solve that, Help me to solve that problem **

```
<?php
require('mc_table.php');
$pdf=new PDF_MC_Table();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->Cell(188,12,'Title',1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(47,12,'',0,1);
$pdf->SetWidths(array(47,47,47));
$pdf->Cell(47,12,'Name',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(47,12,'Price',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(47,12,'Code',1,1);
include('db.php');
$sql="Select Name,Price,Code from products";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($dtset=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$name=$dtset['Name'];
$price=$dtset['Price'];
$code=$dtset['Code'];
function GenerateName($name)
{
$nb=1;
$w='';
for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
$w.='$name';
return $w;
}
function GeneratePrice($price)
{
$nb=1;
$p='';
for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
$p.='$price';
return $p;
}
function GenerateCode($code)
{
$nb=1;
$c='';
for($i=1;$i<=$nb;$i++)
$c.='$code';
return $c;
}
for($i=0;$i<1;$i++)
$pdf->Row(array(GenerateName(),GeneratePrice(),GenerateCode()));
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: As mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (please refer to [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)) you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). And please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your pages and let us know which error are thrown

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GenerateName() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\test2\index.php:24) in C:\wamp\www\test2\index.php on line 21

Comment: error speaks for itself... then `require_once` [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) might be useful

Comment: give me solution

Comment: I gave you all you need mate :) the solution is making sure you don't try to include/declare twice !

Comment: now check ,but still error on this code

Comment: check where you declare `GenerateName()` first, in which file ? `mc_table.php` ? `db.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the functions inside the `while` loop. On the first iteration they get declared, but in the next iteration you try to declare them again. You can't do that, that's why you get the error message:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GenerateName() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\test2\index.php:24) in C:\wamp\www\test2\index.php on line 21

Move the functions outside of the while loop so they get declared only once.